# Insert HTML on Radio Label on Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I have a form that has a radio button on it (Formtastic 1.2.4), and It works just fine with the :collection I'm passing. The problem is I want some part of the text to be affected by some CSS, but the :collection attribute does not let me put in HTML.

Here's my code:

```
= subscription.input :plan_type_id, :as => :radio, :label => false, :wrapper_html => {:class => "plan_type"}, :collection => { @plans[:premium_yearly][:description]+number_to_currency(@plans[:premium_yearly][:amount], :precision => 2) => @plans[:premium_yearly][:value], @plans[:premium_monthly][:description]+number_to_currency(@plans[:premium_monthly][:amount], :precision => 2) => @plans[:premium_monthly][:value] }
```

Has you may may see, I build the label I want to show with my @plans variable and the :collection attribute.

Is there any way I can modify the way it renders the label, I want to put some css to some part of the label.

I want something like this:

```
= subscription.input :plan_type_id, :as => :radio, :label => false, :wrapper_html => {:class => "plan_type"}, :collection => { @plans[:premium_yearly][:description]+'<b>'+number_to_currency(@plans[:premium_yearly][:amount], :precision => 2)+'<\\b>' => @plans[:premium_yearly][:value], @plans[:premium_monthly][:description]+'<b>'+number_to_currency(@plans[:premium_monthly][:amount], :precision => 2)+'<\\b>' => @plans[:premium_monthly][:value] }
```

Thanks in advanced.

I've tried using :member_label to try and print it the way I want it, but all I get is a radio with Yes or No options.